# Saving data with np.savetxt() in Python Error: Mismatch between array dtype and format specifier

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, astropy

I am trying to save the data in four lists into a txt file with np.savetxt, and I am receiving an error. I have never used this before and am not sure what array type and format specifier are.

```
'Create a txt file with my lat, lon, alt, and time data, with each in a seperate column'

#np.savetxt('file_numpy.txt', zip(lat, lon, alt, ), fmt="%i %5.2f")
np.savetxt('file_numpy.txt', zip(myT, lat, lon, alt))
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-ecd6fd3c8a48> in <module>()
     10 
     11 #np.savetxt('file_numpy.txt', zip(lat, lon, alt, ), fmt="%i %5.2f")
---> 12 np.savetxt('file_numpy.txt', zip(myT, lat, lon, alt))

/Users/mrmenzel/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.pyc in savetxt(fname, X, fmt, delimiter, newline, header, footer, comments)
   1217                     raise TypeError("Mismatch between array dtype ('%s') and "
   1218                                     "format specifier ('%s')"
-> 1219                                     % (str(X.dtype), format))
   1220         if len(footer) > 0:
   1221             footer = footer.replace('\n', '\n' + comments)

TypeError: Mismatch between array dtype ('|S32') and format specifier ('%.18e %.18e %.18e %.18e')
```

My data:

```
Lat:

[<Latitude 27.689176073130298 deg>, <Latitude 48.45032120487385 deg>, <Latitude 48.364205712585104 deg>, <Latitude 27.538849564221568 deg>, <Latitude -0.03713701451174661 deg>, <Latitude -27.6161238116795 deg>, <Latitude -48.41635545462272 deg>, <Latitude -48.38265336989975 deg>, <Latitude -27.529850683687265 deg>, <Latitude 0.0929886673818169 deg>]

Lon:

[<Longitude -11.245369984319288 deg>, <Longitude 24.602646508968856 deg>, <Longitude 77.51869866724904 deg>, <Longitude 113.20045826221023 deg>, <Longitude 135.11667887191157 deg>, <Longitude 157.05927178662643 deg>, <Longitude -167.1439210586291 deg>, <Longitude -114.16647366586022 deg>, <Longitude -78.40457926191569 deg>, <Longitude -56.45443351644551 deg>]


Alt:

[<Quantity 409193.55555070826 m>, <Quantity 418422.38904031017 m>, <Quantity 419775.9010528204 m>, <Quantity 412775.65686140396 m>, <Quantity 407430.35452421894 m>, <Quantity 410337.3219834759 m>, <Quantity 415810.49056818814 m>, <Quantity 414410.9036345114 m>, <Quantity 406680.40398573445 m>, <Quantity 402944.3590314008 m>]


Time:

['2000-01-01 12:09:16.000', '2000-01-01 12:18:32.000', '2000-01-01 12:27:48.000', '2000-01-01 12:37:04.000', '2000-01-01 12:46:20.000', '2000-01-01 12:55:36.000', '2000-01-01 13:04:52.000', '2000-01-01 13:14:08.000', '2000-01-01 13:23:24.000', '2000-01-01 13:32:40.000']
```

Comment: The default output format of `np.savetxt` assumes that the input is an array of floats. You don't seem to have floats (or an array, for that matter).

Comment: I updated my question so that it includes my data

Comment: Can you force the data to be entirely numerical? I mean the variable being named Lat seems to be pretty clear on what the data is so you could just have Lat = [27.689..., 48.450..., ...] then np.savetxt should work

Comment: I'm not sure how to force it to be numerical, right now it's just how [Astropy](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/api/astropy.coordinates.EarthLocation.html)  is outputting it from `loc = coord.EarthLocation(...)`  and  `lat.append(loc.lat)`  `lon.append(loc.lon)`  `alt.append(loc.height)`

Comment: You need to dig into `Astropy` to find its own version of `savetxt`, or how to create arrays from this kind of data. You could also explore the most general format, `%s`.

Comment: I would encourage you to use the [`astropy.table`](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/) format to save these quantities.